# How to execute a Cloud Function after Dataflow job has succeeded?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I want to trigger Cloud Function only if Dataflow job execution completed successfully.

Cloud Function should not be triggered if Dataflow job is failed.

I am running a Dataflow job using a Dataflow template (jdbc to BigQuery) from the the Dataflow UI.

There is no option to trigger any Cloud Function or something after job execution. Also, I can't make changes in template code. What's the way to trigger Cloud Function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't, yet, built it feature for this, but I can propose a workaround.

- Go to Cloud Logging and go to the advanced filter (or to the new UI)
- Enter this filter

```
resource.type="dataflow_step"
textPayload="Worker pool stopped."
```

- Then create a sink (action -> create sink in the new UI)
- Choose PubSub as sink destination (create a new topic for this)
- Save
- Then link the topic to your Cloud Function (either with a push subscription to a HTTP triggered Cloud Functions, or with a Topic Triggered Cloud Functions.

Like this, every end of dataflow job, a new message will be posted to PubSub and your Cloud Function will be triggered.

Comment: Thanks @guillaume blaquiere, it works fine.  doesn't dataflow provide any build in feature for that?

Comment: No Dataflow don't generate event for that. But a new feature named [EventArc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/events/audit-logging) is very promising. All the cloud event source aren't present in it, but I think it's the future and you will have this kind of event in. *Note: under the hood, eventarc packages the same process as this one described*

Comment: This solution does not differentiate between successful and failed jobs as we get the "Worker pool stopped." message in both. Is there any filter specific to successful jobs?

Comment: IMO, my solution is obsolete. Prefer Google Workflow with brand new connectors, including [Dataflow Connector](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/dataflow/Overview) and thus orchestrate nicely your different steps

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do something similar before.

https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/PipelineResult.html

```
PipelineResult result = pipeline.run();
State s = result.waitUntilFinish();
if (s.compareTo(State.DONE) == 0)
    return callCloudFunction();
```

Then you can set up your cloud function to be triggered by an http request.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http

Answer (score -1):

You might find this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130103877) to trigger a Cloud Function when Dataflow has finished useful.

There is the ability to determine if a [Dataflow job](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-command-line-intf#jobs_commands) has failed or succeeded from the command line. You can list jobs and check their current status, for example, to check a single job, you can run:

```sh
gcloud beta dataflow jobs describe <JOB_ID>
```

The JDBC to BigQuery template [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/JdbcToBigQuery.java) can be found on GitHub. You could always create a [custom template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates) if you need to make any specific changes.